# Matlab Single Row Vector, while loop that replaces value

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, probability, montecarlo

```
numtrials = 10000;
empty = 0;
for i = 1:numtrials
    seat = zeros(1,100);
    seat(randi(100)) = 1;
     for p = 2:99   % second person in line will look for seat 2, only  up to 99 because I want to see if 99 is zero
         if seat(p) == 0
             seat(p) = 1;
         else
             while seat(randi(100)) == 0
             seat(randi(100)) = 1;
             end
         end
     end
     if seat(100) == 0
         empty = empty + 1;
     end
end
disp(empty)
 X = empty/numtrials;   
disp(['The probability that your seat will be available is ', num2str(X)])
```

100 people are standing in line, the person in the front sits at a random seat, everyone else sits in order. If a person finds their seat taken they sit at another random seat. I'm trying to find the probability that seat 100 will be open by the time the last person in line gets to it. My question is how can I make my while loop look for a seat that is open ( equal to 0) and assign it a one, The part in question is after the Else statement.

Comment: Your current loop regenerates the random number in the loop body, that might be why you're asking this question (but your question is unclear, so I'm only guessing). Generate and store the `randi(100)` value before the `while` loop, check for `seat(this_random_index)==0`, and regenerate the index inside the loop. In this scenario you have to set the given seat to 1 *after* the while loop. Homework^2: do the same thing in a MATLAB-y way, without a while loop (find the nonzero indices of `seat`, pick a single random one from those indices).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `randi` you will get a different number, so you could assign an occupied seat to 1 again. You should use `while true`, generate a random number once, then `break` out of the loop if the seat was unoccupied. You can eliminate that loop entirely by keeping track of seat numbers instead and only picking from the empty seats like this:

```
numtrials = 10000;
empty = 0;
for i = 1:numtrials
    seat = 1:100; %List all seat numbers
    seat = seat(seat~=randi(100)); %Remove a random seat from the list of seats
     for p = 2:99   % second person in line will look for seat 2, only  up to 99 because I want to see if 99 is zero
         if any(seat == p)
             seat = seat(seat~=p);
         else
             s = seat(randi(length(seat))); %Randomly select an empty seat
             seat = seat(seat~=s); %Eliminate this seat
         end
     end
     if any(seat == 100)
         empty = empty + 1;
     end
end
disp(empty)
 X = empty/numtrials;   
disp(['The probability that your seat will be available is ', num2str(X)])
```

EDIT:
The first suggestion would be something like:

```
while true
  s = randi(100);
  if (seat(s) == 0)
    seat(s) = 1;
    break;
  end
end
```

Comment: Concerning your first suggestion, how would set up the break           seat(a) = randi(100);
             while seat(a) == 1
             seat(a) = 1;
             break;

Answer (score 0):

```
disp('The probability that your seat will be available is 1/2');
```

It's called the "Grandma" problem (Gradma is the first person, choosing a random seat). There's no need to code anything, probability is `1/2` : )

Concise version of the proof: first person that seats in either Grandma's seat, or the 100th person seat determines the outcome. And all people (including Grandma) have exactly the same probability of seating in Grandma's seat vs 100th person's seat in all possible scenarios. Complete symmetry.

Comment: The [montecarlo] tag suggests that the point is to practice coding, not to actually solve the greatest mysteries of life.

Comment: Same as all other tags) There's very little chance the coding answer will prove useful to any googler stumbling upon this post. I can easily imagine another situation, however, where people find this page, genuinely searching for the solution to this problem. If this question is not removed, the answer needs to be here.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that students of stochastics classes don't use SO as a source;) But I agree, the question doesn't merit a fully fledged answer (which is why I only left a comment with the solution). Unfortunately we don't have a "*too localized*" close vote reason anymore.